# NSURLConnection downloading continues, when App goes to background

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I am working on an app in iOS 5.0 and I want to use the refined NSURLConnection to download content from the server. I just have a quick question, if the app is not a newsstand app, will NSURLConnection continue to download after the user enters the app to background.

I know I can not invoke a download while the app is not running which is a newsstand feature, but I am not sure if I start the download and app enter background, will it continue?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to request to stay in the background in order to be able to do this... For more information look [at apple docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html), specifically the Background Execution and Multitasking section where it says how to perform finite length tasks... hope it helps